# S4 SDK call takes long time and stopped without error

Tags: s4sdk

I encountered a strange issue.  The execute call to get S/4 Business role authorization details, made by using S/4 SDK takes long time, then stopped without throwing an exception. the code used is shown below. The url is https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/SAP/APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV/getAuthDetails?ID=%27SAP_BR_INVOICING_SPEC_CINV%27&$format=json&sap-client=100&saml2=disabled

The call works for some roles, but for some other roles, it takes long time, then stopped without throwing exception.

```
List<IagprivilegeauthDetails>       authDataList = new 
   DefaultS4cBusinessRoleMetadataService()

   .getAuthDetails(bRoleId).execute(configContext);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with "it stopped"? Was the list empty/null, did it never return at all? If the call succeeds for some roles but not others it seems that the issue lies with the service you are using. So please get in contact with the creator/maintainer of the service and clarify what the problem is. Please also add your findings as an answer here, so that others might benefit from that!

Comment: As you can see, the service works from browser. Because it is called in batch job, it never comes back without exception.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "called in batch job"? Also, are there any stacktraces or logs you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation and other reports of issues like this we found the problem:
A library that we use did not close all HTTP resources properly.

After upgrading the library this should be fixed with version [2.19.0](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sap.cloud.s4hana*%20AND%20v:2.19.0).